# Using coffee-script with rails3.1 ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby, node.js, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, npm

I have rails 3.1 installed, and I try to use coffee script.

I get this:

```
node.js:63
   throw e;
         ^
Error: print() has moved. Use require('sys') to bring it back.
  at node.js:12:11
```

I use nodejs, 0.5.5 and npm 1.0.27

Have anybody seen this error?
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/gf3/Jerk/issues/3   -  same problem in other project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move to the stable branch of Node.js and all should be fine.

Comment: Just to clarify: The even (0.4.x) releases of Node.js are stable, the  odd (0.5.x) are more experimental. So, it's safest to downgrade to 0.4.x (unless you're on Windows, in which case dealing with 0.5.x is probably better than the alternative—Cygwin—at this point).